# What Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL)

Tags: android

I am facing the following crash in my device:

`10-06 13:01:51.718  3094  3094 F libc : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 3094 (surfaceflinger), pid 3094 (surfaceflinger)`

**FATAL Signal 6** I am getting some info online, but not about **code -6 SI_TKILL**.

Can someone please help to understand what is **code -6 SI_TKILL**?